# How to create and use same ssl certificate on RabbitMQ server and Spring Boot App?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, tomcat, rabbitmq, springboot

can a single ssl certificate either from CA or self signed be used for RabbitMQ server and for Spring boot app?
I have RabbitMQ server running on one machine and Spring boot App running on another machine. Client app communicates to RabbitMQ over AMQP and to Spring boot App over REST API.I want to use same SSL certificate on both serves,so that client doesn't need different certificates for client authentication.

Answer (score 0):

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62690/can-i-use-a-single-ssl-cert-on-two-different-servers

Technically if the hosts use the same FQDN they can (I don't advise this unless the applications is hosted from a single server). Or if you have a cert that uses SANs:

https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-ssl-san/

The best solution is a wild card certificate in this instance.